# Can a Vietnamese use a Schengen visa to visit Israel?

Tags: visas, schengen, israel, vietnamese-citizens

I have a Vietnamese passport with Schengen visa and am currently staying in France.

Can I visit Israel with this passport or do I need to apply for an Israel visa from the Israel Embassy?

Comment: Any reason why you think a Schengen visa might allow to enter a country which is outside the Schengen agreement and not even in the same continent ?

Comment: @DumbCoder Because some countries do that.

Comment: At first, I think there would be some accords between Israel and Schengen , so that is what I am trying to ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you need a visa. From [TIMATIC](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=VN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IL&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) (courtesy KLM):

> / 27JAN17 / 0828 UTC
>   National Viet Nam (VN)          /Destination Israel (IL)
>    Israel (IL)
>
> Passport required.
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 6 months beyond the period of intended stay.  Passport
>   Exemptions:
>
> - Passengers with an emergency or a temporary passport.
>
> Visa Issuance: Visa required, except for Passengers with a
>   confirmation issued by the Israeli Ministry of Interior can obtain a visa on
>   arrival if they travel in a group of 10 or more.  Additional
>   Information:
>
> - Travelers can:
> - enter Jordan over land directly from occupied territory
> - enter occupied territory overland directly from Jordan.
> - Former nationals of Israel holding a foreign passport
>
> Warning:
>   - Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.
>
> Timaticweb Version 1.3 27 January 2017

Comment: is it possible for an invidual to take visa on arrival ? it would take time if apply in France

Comment: @ThoVo see above. group of 10 or more indicates organised tour groups only.

Comment: many thanks, so it is clear that I need a visa to get there